# email-spec destroys my rake cucumber:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec, cucumber

At the beginning this worked fine:

```
$ rake cucumber:all
```

---

But then

```
$ script/plugin install git://github.com/bmabey/email-spec.git
remote: Counting objects: 162, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (130/130), done.
remote: Total 162 (delta 18), reused 79 (delta 13)
Receiving objects: 100% (162/162), 127.65 KiB | 15 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (18/18), done.
From git://github.com/bmabey/email-spec
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

And

```
$ script/generate email_spec
      exists  features/step_definitions
      create  features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb
```

And I add 'require 'email_spec/cucumber' in

> /feature/support/env.rb

so it looks somethinng like:

```
 require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')
 require 'cucumber/rails/world'
 require 'cucumber/formatter/unicode' # Comment out this line if you don't want Cucumber  Unicode support
 require 'email_spec/cucumber'
```

and now:

```
rake cucumber:all
```

gives me this error:

```
$ rake cucumber:all --trace
(in /Users/leonardodarioperna/Projects/frestyl/frestyl)
** Invoke cucumber:all (first_time)
** Invoke cucumber:ok (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute cucumber:ok
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.4.4/lib:lib" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.4.4/bin/cucumber"  --profile default
cucumber.yml was not found.  Please refer to cucumber's documentation on defining profiles in cucumber.yml.  You must define a 'default' profile to use the cucumber command without any arguments.
Type 'cucumber --help' for usage.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995:in `sh'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `sh'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `sh'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1029:in `ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.4.4/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:68:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.4.4/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:138:in `define_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

**WHY?**

but the command:

```
$ cucumber
```

still works

Any idea?

PS
cucumber (0.4.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cucumber.yml file in your project root folder and try again.

Comment: It works!
1. I've created a cucumber.yml inside the root folder
2. I wrote inside:
default: --format pretty features
3. $ rake cucumber:all

Thank you Paolo!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cucumber
```

and

```
$ rake cucumber
```

or

```
$ rake cucumber:all
```

are two different commands.  The rake commands expect a cucumber.yml file to tell it what options to pass to the cucumber executable.  In a rails app, the default location is config/cucumber.yml

An example cucumber.yml file would be:

```
default: --format progress features
```

Comment: I have 2 cucumber.yml in my app:
/vendor/gems/rspec-1.2.9/cucumber.yml
that look like this: http://pastie.org/879942
and the other
/vendor/plugins/email-spec/examples/rails_root/cucumber.yml
that looks like this: http://pastie.org/879943

Why it says it can find it if that file never changed?

Comment: try copying the one from /vendor/plugins/email-spec/examples/rails_root/cucumber.yml into your config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should create a new initializer under features, (I use email_spec.rb)  since cucumber will overwrite env.rb when you upgrade.

`features/support/email_spec.rb`

```
require 'email_spec/cucumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar, the one Paolo mentioned worked for me too. But the only problem was I already had cucumber.yml in config folder, why should I create the new cucumber.yml in root. Then, I looked at cucumber.yml and removed '--strict', because I have some undefined steps.

Here is how my cucumber.yml looked before:

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

Here is after the change:

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --tags ~@wip
```